# Trouble getting getJSON to display values from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, django

I am having trouble displaying the contents of a `$.getJSON` call. I have this code which retrieves some JSON data from a page.

```
var loadItems = function() {
if (hasNextPage === false) {
    return false
}
pageNum = pageNum + 1;
var url = baseUrl + "json/" + pageNum + '/';
var jqxhr = $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    var a = [];
    $.each(data.itemList, function (item) {
            a.push("<li>" + item.title + "</li>");

    });
    $("<ul/>", {html: a.join(" ")}).appendTo("#anchor");

});
jqxhr.complete(function () { alert('done!'); $(window).bind('scroll', loadOnScroll); });
};
```

The idea is just to load a page dynamically based on scroll position, and get the JSON contents of that page (for an infinite scroll effect). The JSON structure is something like this:

```
{ "key1": val1, "key2": val2, "itemList": [ {"title": "title", "author": "author", "id": 100, "slug": slug, }, ... ] }
```

The important values are in itemList, where I have to retrieve data that will get plugged into my django template, which in turn will get some data from the view. Everything seems to work just fine, except that I can't access the data in itemList. Nothing seems to get pushed into the array. because nothing gets displayed on the page (namely, the `<li>` that should be created). This seems to be a simple implementation of a basic ajax move, but its not working.

EDIT:

I've done some bug tracking and have found that the code never executes the $.each loop. Not sure how to resolve this though.

Comment: do console.log(data) and see what you are getting.

Comment: its not throwing anything back

Comment: that means you are not getting data.do console.log(url) and check whether it is correct or not.

Comment: naturally, but its strange because I am fetching the pages with the json content... So its just that its not extracting data from those pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be using error log to check what is going wrong:and always use index,obj format in `$.each` to be safe.

```
 $.getJSON(url).success( function( data ) {
                    console.log(data);
    $.each(data.itemList, function (index, item) {
    a.push("<li>" + item.title + "</li>");
   });
    $("<ul/>", {html: a.join(" ")}).appendTo("#anchor");

                }).error(function(error){
                    console.log(error);// see if you are getting in error log..
                });
```

and your json data is also wrong it should be something like this:

```
{ "key1": "val1",
 "key2": "val2",
 "itemList": 
[
 {
"title": "title", "author": "author", "id": 100, "slug": "slug" 
},....... 
]

 }
```

try with corrected data it will work.
you can check your data here:http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: Yeah you're right. When I ran the error console I got a ready state 4, with a status 200, suggesting that the json wasn't correctly parsed. Thanks a lot for helping me, this has been invaluable.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the problems in your code when you using

```
 $.each() //It should using for dictionary.
```

So I have two solutions for you

1) You can use forEach method.

ex:

```
`if(data != null && data.itemList.length > 0)
{
    data.itemList.forEach(function (item) {
                       a.push("<li>" + item.title + "</li>");
                       });
}`
```

==> This way will work for IE 10+, and the other browers.

2) Using the $.each method

ex:

```
if(data != null && data.itemList.length > 0)
{
   $.each(data.itemList, function (key, item) {
            a.push("<li>" + item.title + "</li>");
    });
}
```

==> Your Json data is dictionary type, so if you use $.each you need to define two variable with

```
key: is the key of data.
item: is the value of data.
```

Note: this way will be worked for all browers version.

Hope this can helps you.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your 'item' is an index, not an 'object' as you want. you have to use the second parameter:

```
$.each(data.itemList, function (index, item) {
        a.push("<li>" + item.title + "</li>");
});
```

also, where is `hasNextPage` defined? is it defined? you might also shorten that to:

```
if (!hasNextPage) return;
```

Comment: hey, I changed the function to `function (index, item)` but it still doesn't work. Also, hasNextPage is defined as a global, I just didn't include its definition in the snippet above.